# Is there an elegant way to print all items in one way and the last item the other in python

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am iterating the list of tuples and adding html tags like this:

```
for p in some_list_of_tuples:
    print p[0] + "<br>",
    print p[1] + "<br><br>",
```

The problem I have is that I do not want to add `<br><br>` for the second item in the last tuple. Is there an elegant way to achieve this without using a list index or using if/else statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print "<br><br>".join("{}<br>{}".format(*data) for data in some_list_of_tuples)
```

(or `"<br><br> "` and `"{}<br> {}"` if you really need the spaces from your original code).

`str.join()` is in fact good for inserting strings *in-between* other strings, so this does what you need.

Comment: Whatever happened to my elegant, **readable** Python language? :-)

Comment: I believe that this is quite readable: `join()` simply inserts something between strings, and the `format()` shows clearly what these strings are. For a simpler code, `for data in …` could be `for (item0, item1) in …` and `format(*data)` could instead be `format(item0, item1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (well, it uses a slice and an index, but I believe it's quite readable):

```
for item1, item2 in some_list_of_tuples[:-1]:
    print item1 + "<br>",
    print item2 + "<br><br>",
else:
    item1, item2 = some_list_of_tuples[-1]
    print item1 + "<br>",
    print item2,
```